# Ecommerce tracking, products not listed in analitycs

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google tag manager to implement ecommerce analytics. So, following this: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions
I'm getting this in the preview: 
[image]

..looks like everything is being sent.
When I come to Google Analytics, Ecommerce user listing results the most recent ones, I'm seeing the amount of the products tracked, but not their prices (which I'm also sending). I'm expecting to see a list of products with their names and SKUs, prices, but get only a number of how many product were tracked. 
[image]

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How long did you wait it takes 24 - 48 hours for data to complete processing

Comment: 8 hours now.. But I've implemented such thing before, but without tag manager, I remember it took a minute to show up. And as I can see, it is the price that is not been registered, I wonder why..

Comment: And also, the number "Product list views" is being updated, as on the first picture: 560. So it should be processed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataLayer code seems to just for pushing impressions. If you want it to populate the Sales Performance report you need it to push the other events - `details`, `addToCart`, `checkout` and `purchase`.

At the very least have the dataLayer push out the `purchase` event at the end of your shopping funnel.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the key. Just "detail" and "impressions" do not work alone. You need to have "purchase" to be able to review the impressions. Not sure why is that..

Comment: Well because it's part of Enhanced E-Commerce Analytics and the most important thing about EEC is the value contained in `revenue`. If you think about it, impressions are basically pageviews with a different label, so it's not like there's anything special about that event that couldn't be tracked with vanilla Universal Analytics.